# Stop iCloud from syncing properties in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, uiimage

In my core data database, I have a UIImage, which is the full image. I also have a series of thumbnail versions of the same image. I don't need to sync these, because if they're not there then the app creates them. It'd be faster for it to do this than upload and download them. It'd also take up less iCloud storage space.

Would I be able to stop these properties from syncing?

Comment: u ment u want to stop sync for a some specific fields of coredata entities..?